# Why Docusign authentication need Redirect URL ?? Can we authenticate the API without Redirect URL?

Tags: ajax, rest, authentication, docusignapi

I am trying to use the Docusign API for my development.
But here is one issue with the authentication API .. it needs a Redirect URL.
Because I need to use this API in the Rest API tool and in AJAX call. so it is not possible to provide the Redirect URL .

Can't we call this API without Redirect URL in AJAX or in REST API tool.

Answer (score 0):

This is part of the rule of OAuth 2.0
The redirectUrl is used to actually redirect the user somewhere after they authenticate.
But it is also used to ensure that the clientId (integration key) was used by the right app to go to a valid URL that was registered with them. This is to protect from potential phishing.
So, yes, you need to have one, and you need to ensure it's registered for your integration key.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is a single page application then you should use OAuth Implicit grant.

If your app is a thick client app, then Implicit grant is also used. In this case, it is common to use a private scheme such as `larrysApp://app/redirect` as the redirect url and register the scheme with the OS so your app will receive the URL.

Also, please be sure to NOT use the authentication category of API methods in the DocuSign eSignature API. They're obsolete. Instead, use OAuth, as documented on the [DevCenter](https://developers.docusign.com)